# Appium/Python - Issue with automating spotify app

Tags: python, android, appium, spotify

I was trying to automate the spotify music app on my android device using appium/python.

The goal is to automate the functionalities like play, pause, previous and next.

The app is launched and clicking on play button is successful. **But for the next action(pause/next/prev) its taking too much time(more than 1 minute).**

One thing noted is, if i click on the play button manually(so the song will get paused) the next action(play/next/prev) happening automatically at the same time. My assumption is as the song in playing mode, the song duration timer control is changing and its in turn making some sync issue for appium. Its just an assumption and can be totally wrong.

Which area i need to check to resolve the 'long time for click' issue. Please let me know if any more information is required.

Appium v1.22.2
Python 3.8.5
Spotify 8.7.64.478
Samsung Galaxy s20
Android 12

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The issue got resolved after adding the below line before the click action  : self.driver.update_settings({
                 "waitForIdleTimeout": 100,  })